# How style the text in a searchbar with pixate?

Tags: css, ios7, pixate

I have tried to style the UISearchBar text in my app with pixate. It work only after I dismiss the keyboard, but when I'm writing the text it not use my style:

I'm writting:

[image: I'm writting]

After the keyboard is closed:

[image: After the keyboard is closed]

This is my current CSS:

```
text-field {
    color: black;
    background-color : @colorEditTexto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-width: 8px;
    border-color: gray;
    height: 30px;

    placeholder {
        font-style: italic;
        color: darkgray;
    }
}
search-bar {
    background-color: @colorBarra;
    -ios-tint-color: white;
    color: white;

    text-field {
        color: white;
        placeholder {
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally do this:

```
for (UIView* subview in [[self.subviews lastObject] subviews]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)subview;
        textField.styleMode = PXStylingNone;
        [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#014148"]];
        textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

I have this style interfering:

```
text-field {
    color: black;
    background-color : @colorEditTexto;
    placeholder {
        font-style: italic;
        color: darkgray;
    }
}
```

that is why is necessary to set `PXStylingNone`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `highlighted` pseudo-class like this:

```
search-bar {
    background-color: @colorBarra;
    -ios-tint-color: white;
    color: white;

    text-field {
        color: white;
        placeholder {
            color: white;
        }
    }
    text-field:highlighted {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Somehow the UITextField that is contained in the UISearchBar isn't affected, no matter how broadly I try to style "text-field".

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a styleId or styleClass on your search bar and style it directly versus using the element name. For example:

```
#mySearchBar { ... }
```

Also, Pixate doesn't currently support the searchFieldBackgroundImageForState property, but we'll add that soon to more properly set the background image of a Search Bar.

And lastly, to set the color of the text, right now, this is probably the best way, in code:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: This don't work. I forgot to mention that I have already apply this workaround. If the bar style is UISearchBarStyleMinimal (the only way to have the background color applied) then the text is black when writing and only become white when lost focus.